# Openshift Cron bash No such file or directory

Tags: bash, cron, openshift

I have created the next script in cron cartridges:

```
#!/bin/bash
status=`curl -s -D - http://someurl.xxx/ -o /dev/null | grep "HTTP" | grep "200"`
today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

echo $today "["$status"]" >> ${OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR}/traza.log

if [ "$status" != "" ]; then
    echo $today "OK:" $status >> ${OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR}/traza.log
else
    echo $today "KO:" $status >> ${OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR}/traza.log
fi
```

I have this error: `line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory`

But exit its ok:

```
2014-07-23 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
2014-07-23 OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

If I remove the first line, then script dosent work and I have this error:

```
line 1: status=HTTP/1.1: No such file or directory
```

And exit:

```
2014-07-23 []
2014-07-23 KO:
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

**Solved**

The problem was the file format. Originally was: 
End of line -> Linux and UTF-8 Format

Changed by: 
End of line -> Dos \ Windows and UTF-8 w / o BOM Format

Comment: My script is in two paths:

`./app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/cron/minutely/checkServer`
`./app-deployments/2014-07-24_09-52-07.640/repo/.openshift/cron/minutely/checkServer`

Isn't copied to /bin

Comment: Do "which bash" or "whereis bash" and whatever is the output, put that path in the first line. i.e. if "which bash" shows your "bash" executable is available at /usr/bin/bash, then change #!/bin/bash to #!/usr/bin/bash in your file (first line)